# "Scale Change" in Sakurai's Modern Quantum Mechanics

Tags: quantum-mechanics

On p. 141 in chapter 2 of the second edition of Sakurai's *Modern Quantum Mechanics*, the authors write the following:

> Consider some function of position at $\mathbf{x}$, $F(\mathbf{x})$. At a neighboring point we obviously have $$F(\mathbf{x}+d\mathbf{x})\approx F(\mathbf{x})+(\nabla F)\cdot d\mathbf{x}.$$ But suppose we apply a scale change as we go from $\mathbf{x}$ to $\mathbf{x}+d\mathbf{x}$ as follows: $$\left.1\right|_{\text{at $\mathbf{x}$}}\to \left.\left[1+\boldsymbol{\Sigma}(\mathbf{x})\cdot d\mathbf{x}\right]\right|_{\text{at $\mathbf{x}+d\mathbf{x}$}}.$$ We must then rescale $F(\mathbf{x})$ as follows: $$\left.F(\mathbf{x}+d\mathbf{x})\right|_\text{rescaled}\approx F(\mathbf{x})+\left[(\nabla+\boldsymbol{\Sigma})F\right]\cdot d\mathbf{x}.$$

What precisely do the authors mean by a "scale change", either in mathematical or physical terms? I observe that the desired result can be obtained by replacing the number $F(\mathbf{x})$ in the RHS of the original expression by $F(\mathbf{x})+F(\mathbf{x})\boldsymbol{\Sigma}(\mathbf{x})\cdot d\mathbf{x}$.